# Запятая или тире перед «следовательно»?

Tags: вводные-слова

Как правильно, а как – нет?

1.1. Купила эти ты чёботы – следовательно, так же можешь и сейчас сделать.

2.2. Купила эти ты чёботы – следовательно так же можешь и сейчас сделать.

2.1. Купила эти ты чёботы, следовательно так же можешь и сейчас сделать.

2.2. Купила эти ты чёботы, следовательно, так же можешь и сейчас сделать.

Comment: Это высказывание чересчур замысловато, а не понимая толком смысла и назначения фразы, невозможно составить мнения об уместности постановки того или иного знака препинания.

Comment: Леопольд, нельзя ли привести (в комментариях) Ваш вариант перевода фразы «1.1.» на английский язык?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я выбираю вариант с запятой после вводного слова "следовательно" и постановкой тире:

*Купила эти ты чёботы – **следовательно,** так же можешь и сейчас сделать.*

**Пояснение**

1. Здесь БСП с подчеркнутым **условным** значением (***если...то***), слово "следовательно" используется в значении вводного слова, можно сравнить с похожим предложением из **[Справочника по пунктуации:](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum?layout=item&id=58_220)**

*Послал он мне крест – **значит (= следовательно)**, меня он любит.* И. Тургенев, Живые мощи.

2. Если мы не обособляем слово "следовательно", то считаем его **союзом** со значением следствия, а у нас значение "если...то".
3. При постановке **запятой** в БСП мы не обозначаем подчеркнутую паузу (**упрощенное оформление**), а для приведенного предложения паузу/тире желательно обозначить.

**Приложение (для сравнения)**

Постановка знаков в предложении со значением следствия в **[Справочнике по пунктуации](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum?layout=item&id=58_675):**

*Я – русский человек, **следовательно** имею право это сказать.* С. Надсон, Дневники.

Answer (score 1):

Зачем вы принимаете **неправильные** ответы? **Редактирую свой ответ, т.к. был получен ответ от эксперта.**

**Верным** будет  только вариант будет **2.1**: "Купила эти ты чёботы, следовательно так же можешь и сейчас сделать.".

***Правило***:

> Вводные слова и сочетания слов, стоящие на границе однородных членов
> или **частей сложного предложения** и относящиеся к следующему за ними
> слову или предложению, не отделяются от него запятой (вторая запятая
> опускается с целью указания на отнесенность вводного слова к
> последующей части предложения): Лось шел скачками в сторону озер,
> **должно быть** спешил на водопой

У нас нетипичная ситуация, однако нормы все равно действуют.
Перед нами сложное предложение, где от условного союза (если...значит [следовательно]) осталась только одна часть - **следовательно**.

В реальности ваше предложение выглядело бы так:
"**Если** купила эти ты чёботы, **следовательно** так же можешь и сейчас сделать".

---

Какая норма применима к данному предложению?

> Значит (=следовательно). Часть двойного союза «если... значит» или
> «раз... значит». Запятая ставится на стыке главного и придаточного
> предложения. Если встретиться нам не придется, значит такова наша
> судьба. Если я это сказал, значит я увлекся.

**После союза никаких знаков быть не может!**

---

Вы можете спросить, почему тогда не ставим **тире**?

**Ответ прост**: при вводном слове (вводном слове в значении союза) должна стоять запятая (только отделяющая от предшествующей части), а никак не тире. Знак тире в случае с вводными словами недопустимо использовать.

---

В литературе встречается множество подобных примеров, сравните хотя бы с этими:

> Предупрежден, **значит** вооружен! (вводное слово в значении союза)

> **Если** предупрежден, **значит** вооружен! (двойной союз)

Comment: Если есть тире, пишет потом РАН, то отделение запятой надо делать. Мы не отделяем, только если нет ничего – ни скобок, ни тире. Следовательно, правильно и так: «Купила эти ты чёботы – следовательно, так же можешь и сейчас сделать», и так: «Купила эти ты чёботы, следовательно так же можешь и сейчас сделать».

Comment: http://orthographia.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=127#pp127. (Оно в конце 93-го параграфа.)

Comment: @Леопольд-мэтр Там такого нет! Конкретные слова сюда скопируйте.

Comment: _Предупрежден, значит вооружен_ и _Если предупрежден, значит вооружен_ — бред. В справочнике Розенталя (http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=122) в пункте 9-13 сказано, что слово _значит_ всегда выделяется с двух сторон. Так что только так: _Предупрежден, значит, вооружен_ (между частями сложного предложения); _Если предупрежден, значит, вооружен_ (структурный элемент).

Answer (score 0):

Купила эти, ты, чёботы, – следовательно, так же можешь и сейчас сделать. Ввиду того что покупка обуви - чёбот, никак не сочетается со словом "сделать", думаю тире оправдана. И также присутствует временной и логический разрыв между купила и сейчас.

Купила чёботы - следовательно можешь повторить сейчас.

Купила (**вчера**) - можешь повторить **сейчас**.

Вообще вся правая часть этой конструкции лишена четкой предикации: то ли акцент на ты, то ли на эти, то ли на купила, то ли на чёботы, то ли просто повествование; в то время как вторая часть, абсолютна предикативна к "и сейчас сделать".

"Ты" я так понимаю частица, которая почти лишнее слово, вместо знака препинания?

Купила эти, чёботы.? Следовательно: так же можешь и сейчас сделать.

Comment: «_Купила эти **ты** чёботы…_» равно: «_Ты купила эти чёботы…_». **Запятыми «ты» выделять не нужно!**

Comment: @Слава это если ты частица, ты не обязательно частица.

Comment: Почему частица? Местоимение. Я, ты, он…

Comment: @Слава "4. им. п. ты в знач. частицы. Разг. В сочетании с междометиями употребляется для усиления выражаемого ими значения. — Ах, ты, гадость какая! — с отвращением сказал он, встал и зашагал по комнате. — Как паскудно на душе! Вересаев, На повороте." Не ленись, ты, погугли) ну там с междометьем, но ввиду специфичности предложений Тыквина-Леопольдоского, думаю, междометьем можно пренебречь)